# Put List<T> in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a model:

```
public class BandModel
{
    public string BandName { get; set; }
    public CountryModel Country { get; set; }
    public GenreModel Genre{ get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

And there is a class that returns me an List of these classes

```
public class FullBandProcessor        
{
    public static async Task<List<BandModel>> LoadFullBandInformation()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:11727/api/Bands";

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                List<BandModel> result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<BandModel>>();

                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to show an List of these objects in WPF, but I don't know how to do it - it's completely green in WPF.

Here I tried to use `ObservableCollection`, implement `get` in it so that it calls `LoadFullBandInformation` so that later it can bind to this property in xaml, but something doesn't work for me.

```
private ObservableCollection<BandModel> _BandModels; 


public ObservableCollection<BandModel> bandModels
    {
        get
        {
            return _BandModels = FullBandProcessor.LoadFullBandInformation();
        }
        private set
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe `await` is missing when you call `LoadFullBandInformation()`

Comment: no, await didn't help

Comment: The code you wrote here doesn't even compile so how can we be expected to debug a different problem you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use data binding and an item template to achieve this. Plus you actually need to await your call to `FullBandProcessor.LoadFullBandInformation();` somewhere. Here is the C# code changed to work:

```cs
public class YourClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<BandModel> BandModels { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<BandModel>() // initialise it as empty

    // Constructor
    public YourClass()
    {
        SetBandModels();
    }

    private async Task SetBandModels()
    {
        // Add a try/ catch block
        var bands = await FullBandProcessor.LoadFullBandInformation().ConfigureAwait(false);
        BandModels = new ObservableCollection<BandModel>(bands);
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML, you create a `<ListView>` and it's item template and bind. Like so:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BandModels}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content={"Binding BandName}" /> // Add more controls with more bindings
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: BandModels = new ObservableCollection<BandModel>(bands);
BandModels shows error: "Property or indexer 'YourClass.BandModels'  cannot be assigned to -- it is read only ".

Comment: Whoops, sorry, updated the code and added `private set;` to the property description

Answer (score -1):

`LoadFullBandInformation` returns `List<BandModel>`, while `_BandModels` is an `ObservableCollection`.

You should replace:

```
 get
 {
    return _BandModels = FullBandProcessor.LoadFullBandInformation();
 }
```

with

```
 get
 {
    return _BandModels = new ObservableCollection<BandModel> (FullBandProcessor.LoadFullBandInformation());
 }
```

Comment: `LoadFullBandInformation` needs to be `await`ed, this won't compile.